# Case insensitive hash algorithm for use in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, hash

I am using Hasshids (http://hashids.org/node-js/) to generate opague urls in a REST api, that I have created in node. This all works well, but there is one thing I can't get to work, and I can't seem to find anything in the documentation on that... other than the one sentence, that hashes are case sensitive by default. It just doesn't state how to change that default.

I want to use the hash in a URL, and since URLs are case insensitive, I would like my hash to be that as well.

I tried defining the following, thinking that an all lower case alphabet would mean I could just lower case any input:

```
var hasher = new Hasher(config.idHasherSalt, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz');
```

But that doesn't make a difference.

Any input on how to achieve this?

Comment: "since URLs are case insensitive" — No, they aren't. *Parts* of them are, but the whole thing isn't.

Comment: Why not just lowercase all input before computing its hash value if you want a case-insensitive hash value?  Also, keep in mind that an entire URL is only case-insensitive if you control the server environment and make sure that the whole server environment is case-insensitive to both the path and any query parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find how to use custom alphabet in the **hashids** documentation:

```
var Hashids = require("hashids"),
    hashids = new Hashids("this is my salt", 0, "0123456789abcdef");

var id = hashids.encode(1234567);
```

**For more information check: https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.node.js#specifying-custom-id-alphabet**

Comment: I forgot the middle parameter (0 in this case). After adding that, everything works exactly the way I want it to.

Comment: @JayPete Great! I am happy you solved you problem =)